mysql: extract value from another row based on matching a value in a different column to a function of the same col in another row
I have a database of scientific names of birds and want to get the ID of the species that is related to a subspecies. I probably need to use an inner join query but am having trouble constructing it. I can extract the species scientific name (sciname) from the subspecies sciname with a function SubString(sciname, 1, locate(' ', sciname, locate(' ', sciname) + 1)) and try to query with that to find the eID that I want but it gives me a null result - probably because it is only looking at a single record at a time.



eID
ecat
sciname




39
species
Crypturellus noctivagus


40
species
Crypturellus atrocapillus


17341
subspecies
Crypturellus atrocapillus atrocapillus


17342
subspecies
Crypturellus atrocapillus garleppi


41
species
Crypturellus boucardi


17343
subspecies
Crypturellus boucardi boucardi


17344
subspecies
Crypturellus boucardi costaricensis


42
species
Crypturellus kerriae



The output I would like is eID of each subspecies and the eID of its related species.



eID1
eID2




17341
40


17342
40


17343
41


17344
41



I tried this but it didn't work.
select e1.eid, e2.eid from species as e1 
    left join species as e2
    on e1.sciname=e2.sciname 
    where e1.ecat="subspecies" 
       and e2.sciname=(select SubString(e1.sciname, 1, locate(' ', e1.sciname, locate(' ', e1.sciname) + 1)));


SELECT t2.eID eID1, t1.eID eID2
FROM species t1
JOIN species t2 ON t2.sciname LIKE CONCAT(t1.sciname, '%')
WHERE t1.ecat = 'species' AND t2.ecat = 'subspecies'




eID1
eID2




17341
40


17342
40


17343
41


17344
41



fiddle

Worked perfectly! Thanks.
